# Cannot install CUDA 10 for Tensorfow on Ubuntu 18.04 because of Failed CC sanity check

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

I'm following the [guidelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1804_cuda_101) for installing tensorflow 2 and CUDA 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 add NVIDIA package repositories without errors, but I cannot install NVIDIA drivers. When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-430
```

I get the following error:

```
Building for 5.4.0-39-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-39-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-440.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.95.01/build/make.log for more information.
```

...and inside `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.95.01/build/make.log`, I find:

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-440.95.01 for kernel 5.4.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Tue Jun 30 08:53:44 UTC 2020
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: cc: Command not found
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.95.01/build \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1

The C compiler 'cc' does not appear to be able to
create executables.  Please make sure you have
your Linux distribution's gcc and libc development
packages installed.

*** Failed CC sanity check. Bailing out! ***

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.95.01/build/Kbuild:191: recipe for target 'cc_sanity_check' failed
make[2]: *** [cc_sanity_check] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1719: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.95.01/build' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/440.95.01/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic'
Makefile:81: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I use gcc-7 and g++-7, which I selected using `sudo update-alternatives --config` g++/gcc.

The output of `uname -a` is:

```
Linux imt_deep 5.4.0-39-generic #43~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 22 19:05:32 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I solve this error? I really don't understand what is the problem with the compiler. I've also tried installing the drivers setting gcc-5 and g++-5 as default with `update-alternatives --config`, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

first check this error:

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
```

Look here to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276245/how-to-compile-a-kernel-module-against-a-new-source

Then you need to check if you have the build-essentials, because is saying to you that can't find the "dev" packages.

```
The C compiler 'cc' does not appear to be able to create executables.  Please make sure you have your Linux distribution's gcc and libc development packages installed.
```

Finally I suppose that you are in Ubuntu, follow this instructions: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal